# Run 2 different functions in 1 google script

Tags: google-apps-script

Hello I have 2 different scripts that work just fine when run independently, but i want to combine these functions to be on the same script. Is that possible? right now the script ends after running the first function.

```
function createUsers() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var range = ss.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  for (i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {

    var Fname = values[i][0]
    var Lname = values[i][1]
    var email = values[i][2]
    var title = values[i][3]
    var OU = values[i][4]
    var password = "Password"
    // Check if user exist by email address.
    var userFromDirectory = AdminDirectory.Users.list.name
    if (email != userFromDirectory.primaryEmail) {
      try {
        var user = AdminDirectory.Users.insert({
          "primaryEmail": email,
          "password": password,
          "orgUnitPath": OU,
          "changePasswordAtNextLogin": true,
          "name": {
            "familyName": Lname,
            "givenName": Fname,
            "Job Title": title
          }
        })
      } catch (e) { }
    }
    Logger.log(user);
  } // end of if
}

function addGroupMember() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var range = ss.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  for (i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    var email = values[i][2]
    var groupEmail = values[i][5]
    var member = {
      email: email,
      role: "MEMBER"
    };
    try {
      member = AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, groupEmail);
      Logger.log("User %s added as a member of group %s.", email,
        groupEmail);
    } catch (e) { }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function createUsers() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (i = 1; i < vs.length; i++) {
    var Fname = vs[i][0];
    var Lname = vs[i][1];
    var email = vs[i][2];
    var OU = vs[i][4];
    var groupEmail = values[i][5];
    var password = "Password"
    // Check if user exist by email address.
    var userFromDirectory = AdminDirectory.Users.list.name
    if (email != userFromDirectory.primaryEmail) {
      try {
        var user = AdminDirectory.Users.insert({
          "primaryEmail": email, "password": password, "orgUnitPath": OU, "changePasswordAtNextLogin": true,
          "name": { "familyName": Lname, "givenName": Fname, "Job Title": title }
        });
        var member = {email: email,role: "MEMBER" };
        AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, groupEmail);
      } catch (e) { }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This definitely helped! for some reason it did not like the var user = AdminDirectory.Users.insert({
          "primaryEmail": email, "password": password, "orgUnitPath": OU, "changePasswordAtNextLogin": true,
          "name": { "familyName": Lname, "givenName": Fname, "Job Title": title }
        });
so i changed that part back to the original script and everything is working. thank you

Comment: Please post what is working so others can see it